# Python3 Syntax error

Tags: python

I am quite a new user in python. I am making a script to calculate some quantity like below

```
A = sum([( f * Rphi[i,i] + Rt[i,i]) * NN[i,i] for i range(0,2)]) + 2*sum([sum([(f * Rphi[i,j] + Rt[i,j]) * NN[i,j] for j in range(i+1,2)]) for i in range(0,1)])
```

f is defined as scalar value and all two indices quantities are defined as 3x3 matrix in previously.

This is just summing over indices. When I try to compile it, I got:

**Error message**

[image]

The error indicates that there is a syntax problem in the usage of `for I in range(0,1)` But I cannot find the problem in there.

Any comments or advice is really appreciated!

Comment: Likely a mismatched parents or bracket. Try breaking up the expression into something more readable

Comment: looks like you missed the `in` keyword here `for i range(0,2)])`

Comment: Thanks all you guys

Comment: BTW @hlim if you expand your terminal/command line to eliminate the word-wrapping, you'll see that the caret (`^`) in the error message actually lines up under the *first* `range` where the syntax error occurs, so the error message is pointing you to the exact location, as in this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/HXWvpTQ.png) 

Answer (score 0):

`Syntax Errors` are usually when you make a mistake in the code syntax. In this case, your first part of the code is

```
sum([( f * Rphi[i,i] + Rt[i,i]) * NN[i,i] for i range(0,2)])
```

should be

```
sum([( f * Rphi[i,i] + Rt[i,i]) * NN[i,i] for i in range(0,2)])
```

Comment: Oh thanks!... why I am missing this obvious part.. thanks again

Comment: the key is breaking it down into manageable chunks for readability